# Authentification on a website with webRequest lead to error 403

Tags: c#, webrequest

After searching for almost 2 days with my colleagues on Internet, I didn't find a solution that can help me... That's why I require your help :)

My problem here is with a webRequest that can connect to a bank website, connect with an Id and password, go take some informations and give me them back.

Until now, I make it for a Bank and it worked perfectly, but I need to do it with another and for the new bank, what I did before don't want to work.

The big problem is in the response of the request given by the wbesite I try to connect at, I have a : "The remote server returned an error : (403)Forbidden.
I saw that a lot of people on Internet got a problem with webRequest and this 403 error and tried everything that was possible. 
Whatever I try, setting a default header, a header I did myself or anything else I get this error. Even when my ID & Password are false I get this error, so I can't even connect to the website.

My theory for the moment is that I'm trying to connect to a page of the repertory that I don't have access to and that my HttpHeader who comes after the URI for the connection, is not possible and do not work for this bank.

I also tried changing the Thread time ( To see if they do not refuse the access because the connection is not human ) 
I tried to pu the User Agent, it changed nothing.
Something that could help me : Can I pass the connection information in the uri as I did before ? Or is there a another way that would work ?

PS : If you need other or more precise informations, don't hesitate.

Here is the code.

Thank you for your help.

```
public static List<Compte> requeteBank(PopUpWebRequest popup)
    {

        List<Compte> listeCompte = new List<Compte>();
        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();

        string contentHTTPHeader = "_cm_user" + id + "&_cm_pwd" + password;
        byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(contentHTTPHeader);


        string urlConnexion = "https://www.bank.fr/identification/default.cgi"; // This URI doesn't exist, this is for the example
        HttpWebRequest requeteConnexion = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlConnexion);

        //I even tried with this method 
        // I left this here to show you how I made this 
        //string authInfo = popup.identifiant + ":" + popup.password; 
        //requeteConnexion.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + authInfo;
        //var response = requeteConnexion.GetResponse();
        //authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authInfo));

        //The form for the Id & Password is a Method POST
        requeteConnexion.Method = "POST";
        Stream connexionStream = requeteConnexion.GetRequestStream();

        // Sending connection data...
        connexionStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        connexionStream.Close();

        requeteConnexion.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

        requeteConnexion.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

        HttpWebResponse reponseConnexion = (HttpWebResponse)requeteConnexion.GetResponse(); // Error 403
        //Id from the cookies
        Cookie idSession = reponseConnexion.Cookies["IdSes"];
        reponseConnexion.Close();
        [ The rest of the code.... ]
```

Comment: the url scheme is `HTTPS`. Are you sure you don't need `Authentication`? `authInfo` should be bese64 encoded before sending.

Comment: You might want to investigate using `Fiddler` for example. Look for the differences between a normal session and an automated one. I once created an automated payment as well via a bank but I had some difficulties due some cookies being set through javascript

Comment: Or... When all the manual web requests/responses were starting to get too much work and failed too often. I went to use a `Headless Browser`. In my case `PhantomJS`. Which has multiple 'port' interfaces, for C# as well.

Comment: Are you sure the bank accept POST request from another source that itself ? This is a security purpose that in my opinion this kind of website is subscribed to use. Do you ask the bank to know if there is no secured API ?

Comment: Amit Kumar Ghosh : Authentication ? Do you mean the Credentials ? 
I tried putting authInfo in Base64 but I get the error that it's not possible to convert string into byte[]. 

Neijwiert : I used Fiddler a little ( I do'nt really now ow to use it, just discovered it yesterday ) and I can't make a normal session throught a browser because everytime Fiddler is open, I got certification exceptions and cannot go to websites anymore... 
So you think that the cookies set by javascript in the website are making trouble ? I'm going to check it. 
I'll see for PhantomJs, but I'm not really into Js...

Comment: You can override the certificate errors, they are normal. You are performing a MITM attack on yourself. PhantomJS is written in JavaScript but can be used through for example C#

Comment: D4rkTiger : I don't know but that method worked on a another bank who is affiliated to this one. Maybe there is a protection one the post, I don't really know but already asked myself about it. I can't ask the bank about it because as it is a service from my company to other commpanies , they would like to have some money on the service we provide.

Comment: Also why can you not convert a String to bytes? [Encoding.GetBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds4kkd55(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I didn't see that in that point of view, thanks.I'm looking for PhantomJS and see how I can make it with it. I'll keep you in touch. 
Even after Encoding, still same error..

Answer (score 0):

Good news, I found my problem, so I give the full answer to maybe help someone in the future :) 
Thanks everyone who helped me !

Two things where missing in my program to work correctly.

First, all the bank are not the same even if they come from the same subsidiary Company, they do not use the same HTTP header.. 
So i used a addon in Mozilla Firefox who is https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/ to show the Header of the website and of the response when I connect manually.

With that, I added a lot of different information that was in the header of the bank website just under the creation of the request :

```
requeteConnexion.Method = "POST";
requeteConnexion.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
requeteConnexion.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0";
requeteConnexion.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9*/*;q=0.8";
requeteConnexion.KeepAlive = true;
```

My second mistake was in `string contentHTTPHeader = "_cm_user" + id + "&_cm_pwd" + password;`
I removed the spaces between the name and the values and I forgot to put a "=" after the names. 
The good line is 
`string contentHTTPHeader = "_cm_user="+id+"&_cm_pwd="+password;`.

To the people who want to know here does the "_cm_user=" etc... comes from, with the addon I can see when I connect manually this is how the id and the password where send in the Header, i just had to add the exact same thing in my code.

In hope this could help.